# How to Add Specific Value to an Existing Row in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow. This flow gets excel attachment from the email save to a folder. Than this excel file is copied to another excel file which is in another folder. But I have to update some rows after paste.

I'm using update a row action but how can I give the new value to a specific row. I tried to use replace function to make this change but I couldn't do.Also I have to do these changes according to some conditions.

You can find below screenshots of my flow:
[image: flow1]
[image: flow2]

Can I write a specific value manually to the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update a row with a condition after getting rows using "***List rows present in a table***" action. However, "***Update a row***" action requires that you have a "***Key Column***" in the excel table. Also, you can update excel row by directly entering values into the "Update a row action"

Just tested and it worked for me. See the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.